# Problems with circular imports using index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, circular-dependency

#### Given the following file structure:

```html
myFiles
├── index.js
├── getTrue.js
└── dependentGetFalse.js
```

#### And the following code

```html
// index.js
export { getTrue } from './getTrue'
export { dependentGetFalse } from './dependentGetFalse'
```

```html
// getTrue.js
export const getTrue = () => true
```

```html
// dependentGetFalse.js
import { getTrue } from '.'
export const dependentGetFalse = () => !getTrue()
```

Where there's *(what I assume to be)* a circular import between `dependentGetFalse.js` and `index.js`.

What problems will arise from this? Or is it ok to have?

Comment: You do export when you wanna use your functions in others files and import when you wanna use functions in current file from files where you did export.

Answer (score 0):

If your codes run flawless and you are comfortable with them, It is ok to have this circular situation

Comment: Hm in what cases will circular imports causes problems tho? Will Babel or Webpack complain if i try to transpile it or something?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid using `'.'` imports.

Try this:

```
// dependentGetFalse.js
import { getTrue } from './getTrue'
export const dependentGetFalse = () => !getTrue()
```

`index.js` is useful when you try to import something from outside of this folder.

Comment: I understand thats what I SHOULD do, but what problems will arise if I do import with `'.'`? Currently it runs without errors/warnings, and even in my Typescript projects, the Typescript compiler doesn't complain.